# How long should MySQL dump of circa 4Gb take?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to backup two schemas within a MySQL database. I've successfully performed the dump of the first schema which is abut 300Mb in size with the largest table being 126Mb. This took a few seconds.

The second dump of a 4Gb schema (largest table circa 3.5Gb) hasn't completed after an hour. Does this sound reasonable? If yes, why are timings not proportional? Is there anything I can do to speed things up?

Comment: What have you tried to check **why** this takes so long?

Comment: The only thing I could think of doing was to check if it was the big table that was taking so long and it definitely is. If I just run ithe dump on the other tables then it runs in a few seconds. What would you recommend I try to look at the why?